# Get values of json object and fill a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I need to get the values stored in the stock_data variable and show them in the Datatable. But I cannot get the value stored in stock_data. Just one character.:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    let text = info.event.extendedProps.procs;
    var obj = text.split(";");
    var stock_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

    $("#tblProcedimientos").DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: stock_data,
        language: {
            emptyTable: "No hay datos disponibles para mostrar",
            zeroRecords: "No hay datos disponibles para mostrar",
            url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json",
        },
        ordering: false,
    });
    $("#DatosEvento").modal({ backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttJde.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEI7V.png)

Comment: There's no need for `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` That just returns the same array.

Comment: Does DataTables need a 2D array?  Try `data: [stock_data]`

Comment: Could you provide in the question the value for `info`?